# Need a really static field in a generic class, or otherwise how to protect its visibility?

Tags: c#, generics, static, singleton

I want to have a class like:

```
public class Forest<S, T>
{
    static IList<Animal> coolGuys = new List<Animal>();
}
```

But I want `coolGuys` to be really static, which means it has to be unique through the entire lifetime of the application. And right now its not. MS discourages this pattern, ReSharper warns, **but how does one really achieve what I want?**

May be I will have to do more work by creating **another static class** and have a public static field there *or* a public instance field in **another singleton class**. Its ok to have a redundant public class to hold just a static field, but the thing I want to avoid is the **field being public/internal**. I mean `coolGuys` is just meant for `Forest<,>`, why expose the incoherent things to outside world.

```
public class Forest
{
    public static IList<Animal> coolGuys = new List<Animal>(); //want to avoid
}

public class Forest<S, T>
{
    Forest.coolGuys.Add(cutie);
}
```

Any better pattern?

Comment: `public class Forest<S, T>
{
    Forest.coolGuys.Add(cutie);
}`... what?

Comment: @Mehrdad that's just a logic written there - dont take it literally. I just meant I want access to coolguys from Forest<S,T> (and nowhere else)

Comment: Why don't you inject/pass a state provider to `Forest` and use that to privately manage your collection? It's (arguably) cleaner as a pattern and you achieve the object lifetime that you want.

Comment: @TimMedora I can't understand what you mean. What is a state provider? Can you make it an answer if you feel its one way to go about this?

Comment: I wrote up two different approaches for you.

Comment: @TimMedora I'm anyway alerted :)

Comment: Coolguys won't be unique because your class is generic. Generic classes are actually unique types based on their templated parameters. In order to ensure a unique collection for the class you need to provide a repository class; making a separate class to hold the static collection is one way of doing it

Comment: @Charleh I know I know, all that is covered in my question. Just pondering *other ways* to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Approach 1 - Inject a State Provider

1. Create a type to store data.
2. Abstract it with an interface, so you can inject a different provider if desired (e.g. for testing).
3. Consuming class doesn't care about the implementation, other than it guarantees statefulness.
4. Concurrent dictionary takes care of thread safety.

```
public interface IStateProvider
{
    void Store( string key, object value );
    object Get( string key );
}

public class StateProvider : IStateProvider
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _storage = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public void Store( string key, object value )
    {
        // add to storage
    }

    public object Get( string key )
    {
        // get from storage
    }
}

public class Forest<T1, T2>
{
    private IStateProvider _stateProvider;

    public Forest( IStateProvider stateProvider )
    {
        _stateProvider = stateProvider;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // do something with the stateful value
    }
}

// of course, you could do this with a DI framework
var stateProvider = new StateProvider();
var forest = new Forest<Foo, Bar>( stateProvider );
```

### Approach 2 - Base Class

This approach is less elegant but a bit more straightforward.

```
public abstract class ForestBase
{
    private static List<object> _staticList = new List<object>();

    protected List<object> StaticList
    {
        get { return _staticList; }
    }
}

public class Forest<T1, T2> : ForestBase
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        StaticList.Add( 12345 );
    }
}
```

This hides internal data and should give you only one single instance of the static list, versus one instance per combination of generic arguments.

Comment: Just when I wrote the second approach myself! I will go that way since states seems an overkill here in my simple situation

Comment: one tiny note - probably you meant `base.StaticList` instead of  `this.StaticList`. `this` makes code lying a little bit)

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - good catch, intellisense habit (`this.`) for getting autocomplete. Modified.

Comment: @TimMedora can one safely interpret approach 1 is sort of a toned down Flyweight pattern? (where only intrinsic state is involved)

Comment: @mishrsud - I hadn't thought of it that way, but yes, either approach allows you to share/reuse data across an unlimited number of instances.